# getting edittext value from listview showing nullpointerexception

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity which consists a Dialog and Dialog has a listview. Trying to retrive value of edittext which is a row item of listview but getting nullpointerexception.

```
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout); 
    listView = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ListView); 
     for(int i = 0;i<listView.getCount();i++)
     {
         View v = listView.getChildAt(i);
         EditText tempet = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.et);
         String value = tempet.getText().toString();
     }
```

This code is working fine when Listview is in activtiy layout. But not for dialog.

Comment: show more code. How you create dialog, how you init `listview`, stacktrace

Comment: Which line is throwing the NPE? Could be the list view is part of the activity - you might need to pull it from there.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski -  `dialog = new Dialog(this);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);                     listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ListView);`

Comment: @JackBeNimble --- `EditText tempet = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.et);` The value of tempet is null. Listview is part of dialog layout only but this whole code is done in an activity. If this is the reason please suggest some solution of sample code

Comment: If tempet is null, then the NPE would be thrown on the next line, right?

Comment: @JackBeNimble--yes you are right

Comment: update your question for sake of code formating unavailable in comments!

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski- i have just updated the question. Please suggest some solution

Answer (score 0):

> Try to **inflate** the layout first. Example:

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

**View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.*your_layout*, null);**

alertDialog = builder.create();

ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
listViewParadas.setAdapter(*YourAdapter*);

//Here try obtain editText value...

**alertDialog.setView(view);**

alertDialog.show();

> I hope this helps. Cheers